# NSFetchedResultsController crashes in iOS 6 if affectedStores is specified

Tags: ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am seeing a problem exactly like that described here: http://fingertwister.tumblr.com/post/32341639626/coredata-problem-with-multiple-stores-using

ie, two stores, one static the other user-generated. Set up an NSFetchedResultsController to fetch from just one of the stores. When the controller is deallocated, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on an NSArray instance. The code worked perfectly fine in iOS 4 and 5; the crash only occurs in iOS 6.

Zombie analysis shows that the deallocated NSArray being messaged is the 'affectedStores' property of the NSFetchRequest of the NSFetchedResultsController. Just as in the above link, if I remove the [fetchRequest setAffectedStores:...] command, the problem goes away. And, again just as in the linked example, I can't see anything wrong with my own code as far as memory management of that array is concerned.

Docs don't seem to say anything changed in iOS 6 in this area. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue arrises because somewhere in CoreData something goes wrong with memory management, causing the affectedStores-array to be released early.

You can work around this by increasing the reference counter as a hack:
https://gist.github.com/maruno/5451607

Comment: "somewhere in CoreData something goes wrong" ? Please provide answer to this question. Giving a link is not enought, please describe answer in this post.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer as it is a decent workaround of what does seem to be an Apple bug. Thanks for the code snippet.